# How to download lower version SDK like 1.0.0 and 1.2.0?

Tags: bada

We are developing one bada base c++ application . We need to provide application cometibility for Bada 1.0.0, Bada 1.2.0 and Bada 2.0.x. We have successfully build and tested on Bada 2.0.x. Now we are trying to test application on 1.0 and 1.2 and application is not runing on these versions of Bada os. So, I think we need to build appication on respective 1.0 and 1.2 SDKs. We are trying to find out above SDKs to build application but we are not able to find SDK download link from web.

Can any  one help on this?

Comment: Please see this Q/A which is about the same error like yours, [Bada manifest error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746168/bada-manifest-error). best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to know that bada 2.0 environment supports all the versions of the sdk, it means that you can build 1.0 bada application with 2.0 environment, you should just mentioned this in your manifest

Second, not all the versions support all resolutions, this is a schema illustrating this:

version of bada |  resolutions  |  devices

---

1.0          |  480x800      |  wave 1

---

1.1          |  240x400      |  Wave575 , Wave578 , Wave723

---

1.2          |  480x800      |  wave 2

---

2.0          |  480x800      |  wave 3
   2.0          |  320x480      |  wave M/Y
   2.0          |  240x400      |  no official device

So, if you select for example 1.0 in your application, it should run on 1.0, 1.2, and 2.0 devices 
you should just pay attention to the features that are supported in 2.0 and not supported in 1.2 and 1.1, ans also to the methods that are deprecated in 2.0 SDK

Hope I'm clear, if not, just ask ;), best regards

Comment: Hello Friend, I have tried to create manifest for 1.0 and also tried to check it on 1.0 device but it can't run. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Hello, I have tried it but it gives "cannot find -lc-newlib" error and can't generate binary for that.

Comment: You should install the certificate file, in the [bada_Folder]\Tools\sbuild\rootCACert.cer in your device

Answer (score -2):

Check at Samsung SDK archives - http://developer.bada.com/devtools/archives#