# Bada manifest error: cannot find -lc-newlib

Tags: bada

When we changed manifest.xml from 2.0 to 1.2 or 1.0 generated from "Application Manager" and try to build app in 2.0 IDE in bada. I am getting below errors

1. cannot find -lc-newlib  C/C++ Problem
2. cannot find -lm-newlib  C/C++ Problem
3. make: *** [Test.exe] Error 1    C/C++ Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend that you generate a brand new project, specifying bada 1.2 at creation time, then copy all your source/header/resource files into it. There's more to OS version than the manifest; obviously, the compiler/linker settings need to be different, too.